# How to put a line number every line to the algorithm with springer format

Tags: templates, springernature

How do I put a line number on every line of the algorithm with springer format?

for example:

```
    Algorithm 1 algooo
    Input: X= 1
    ,. . . ,
    :1-D data, : size, : the VAR
    Output: : BINARY
   1  Φ ← FUNC(X)
   2 case Φ in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5,5,6,7} do

   3 F ← Call FUNC Algorithm(Φ, X, , ) // Φ denotes
    NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN

   4 end

   5 return F


\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)

\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[algo2e]{algorithm2e} 

\usepackage{algpseudocode}


\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{enumerate}
 
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{stix,bbding,pifont,utfsym,fontawesome}

\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
 \usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees} 
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage{tabularx,graphicx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs} 
    
 \journalname{The Journal of Supercomputing}

%
\begin{document}


\section{CH Algorithm}


\begin{algorithm} [H]
    \KwIn{X= {$y_1$,…,$y_\beta$}:1-D data, $\beta$: size, $\epsilon$: the VAR } 
    \KwOut{$F$: BINARY}
    \BlankLine
    \emph{$\Phi$ $\leftarrow$ FUNC(X)}\;
    
    \Case {$\Phi$ in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5,5,6,7\}} {
        \emph{F $\leftarrow$ Call FUNC Algorithm($\Phi$, X, $\beta$,$\epsilon$ )} 
        // $\Phi$ denotes NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
    }
    \emph{return $F$} \;
    \caption{algooo }
    \label{alg1}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: I used these two packages \usepackage[algo2e]{algorithm2e} 

\usepackage{algpseudocode}

Answer (score 1):

The answer for my question is, Just remove

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[algo2e]{algorithm2e}
```

And use:

```
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
```

with:

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \SetAlgoLined
```

That's it :)

Comment: This is what I suggested doing....

Answer (score -1):

Does it work to use the "linesnumbered" option to `algorithm2e`?

Example:

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)

\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[algo2e,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e} 

\begin{document}
\section{CH Algorithm}
\begin{algorithm} [H]
    \KwIn{X= {$y_1$,…,$y_\beta$}:1-D data, $\beta$: size, $\epsilon$: the VAR } 
    \KwOut{$F$: BINARY}
    \BlankLine
    \emph{$\Phi$ $\leftarrow$ FUNC(X)}\;
    
    \Case {$\Phi$ in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5,5,6,7\}} {
        \emph{F $\leftarrow$ Call FUNC Algorithm($\Phi$, X, $\beta$,$\epsilon$ )} 
        // $\Phi$ denotes NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
    }
    \emph{return $F$} \;
    \caption{algooo }
    \label{alg1}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How use it?????

Comment: Perhaps read the documentation? It's a package option, so `\usepackage[algo2e,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}` will add line numbers. I posted a minimal working example.